# Impossible to drag file on python script

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

I used to handle some files with .py scripts using "sys" library

```
import sys

if len(sys.argv) > 0:
    name = str(sys.argv[1])
```

Now for some reason this way doesn't work. When i drag files .py script stays inactive for interaction. How can i fix this and what are possible reasons for such behaviour? I use python 3.6.2

Comment: Dragging is an operating-system (or GUI) feature that is entirely outside the control of the Python interpreter.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean that when you drag the file to execute, it hangs, this is probably because your file needs arguments to process. If you attempt to run the file in a debugger with no extra arguments you will probably come across the following error:

> list index out of range
>
> > File "C:\SO\running_stuff.py", line 4, in
> >
> > > name = str(sys.argv[1])

This is because your

`name = str(sys.argv[1])`

line is trying to grab the 1st index, which does not exist with no arguments (prompting the list index out of range error). Try

`str(sys.argv[0]`

instead, since you might be looking for the 0th index, not the first. If you are actually looking for the first index, not the 0th, you can require your line

`if len(sys.argv) > 0:`

to be

`if len(sys.argv) > 1:`

instead.

Comment: A note, it’s good to try to run your files from the shell every now and then so you can get the error messages.

Comment: Thank you for reply. Now i back to python 3.7.2 and all  work fine again. But it is still unclear why this doesn't work with lower python version

Comment: You’re sure the code is the same? And usually the small version changes shouldn’t affect your execution that much. It’s possible you’re using a different way of executing or using different code.

Comment: Code is exactly the same. I should notice, when python 3.7.2 installed it's possible to drag any file onto the script and observe that .py file became  highlited like a folder or executable when drag something onto them and no matter what is inside the script. This doesn't happend when python 3.6.2 was used. If it matters, I'm using Windows

Comment: @newMember That is rather perplexing. This is probably not related to the way Python runs the code, but the mechanism through which drag and drop works. You can try doing some debugging like printing out all the args of sys by doing `for args in sys.argv: print (args)`, or logging it into a file. Maybe this could help you debug the issue.

Comment: But I would make sure to run the file from shell first, to make sure there's no interpreter-related errors before drag and drop. It's probably more reliable for debugging.